# How to save decimal numbers that add up in SharedPreferences?

Tags: java, android

The time i dealt with whole numbers (1,2,3,4...) i was able to save the scores using the following code in java:

```
pointsAmount = pointsAmount +10;
    pointsAvailable.setText("C."+pointsAmount);
    SharedPreferences saveCoins = this.getSharedPreferences("mySaverCoins", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    saveCoins.edit().putInt("C.",pointsAmount).commit();
```

I can add 10 points and they add up and save in Saved Preferences, even if i close and open app again my points are always there with this code.

Now i want the `pointsAmount` to be a decimal number `+0.05`. Using the same code with above is not permitting, it is giving me errors. So I used the following code to save coins with decimal numbers. Now the error is, My Coins disappear when i close and reopen the app again:

```
pointsAmount = (pointsAmount +0.05);
    pointsAmount .setText("C."+pointsAmount );
    SharedPreferences saveCoins = this.getSharedPreferences("mySaverCoins", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    saveCoins.edit().putInt("C.",(int)pointsAmount).apply();
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor= saveCoins.edit();
    editor.putString("mySaverCoins", "mySaverCoins");
    editor.commit();
```

I want my coins to be saved when i wake up the app after closing it. What is the problem with my code?

Comment: What's `pointsAmount`? What errors do you get? Why do use `putInt` when you just said you want it to be a decimal number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you save your coins, you're casting what should be a floating-point number to an integer. When you do this, Java simply truncates the number, meaning anything after the decimal point will be lost. The reason you see the coins getting "wiped" whenever you restart the app is because until you earn 1 coin, your `pointsAmount` variable gets truncated to 0 when saving to your `SharedPreferences`. The easiest way to fix this is to store and restore a floating point number directly:

```
pointsAmount = pointsAmount + 0.05;
pointsAmount.setText("C." + pointsAmount );
SharedPreferences saveCoins = this.getSharedPreferences("mySaverCoins", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
saveCoins.edit().putFloat("C.", pointsAmount).apply();
```

To restore:

```
SharedPreferences saveCoins = this.getSharedPreferences("mySaverCoins", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
pointsAmount = saveCoins.getFloat("C.", 0);
```

Comment: Thanks big broe, its been some days trying to solve this error, I wish i did programming at school, it looks so simple to you. Um just a beginner and i am doing it on my own from zero knowledge. Your are the best be blessed man